# Difference between scipy.special.boxcox and scipy.stats.boxcox

Tags: python, scipy, transformation, scaling

In my program, I am applying box cox transform to my data and I am interested to reverse the box-cox transformation at a certain step through my experiment. However I noticed there are two variants of boxcox:

- [scipy.special.boxcox](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.boxcox.html)
- [scipy.stats.boxcox](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html)

I learned that the first option has a function that reverses the box cox transform [here](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.inv_boxcox.html).

However I just want to know why in [scipy.special](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.16.0/reference/generated/scipy.special.boxcox.html) the lambda parameter cannot be `None` while in [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html) it could be. In my code I am actually using [scipy.stats](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.boxcox.html) and the Lamda is None. Now if I want to revert to using [scipy.special](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.inv_boxcox.html) in order to use its reverse function, what should I set lamda to ?

Here is my current code:

```
            elif self.output_box:
                y_train, self.y_train_lambda_ = boxcox(y_train)
                y_test, self.y_test_lambda_ = boxcox(y_test)
```

Answer (score 1):

They both use the same formula for the transformation so it seems that the only difference is that with scipy.stats you can calculate the optimal lambda for the data.  If you use scipy.stats.boxcox with lambda=None it returns two parameters: the transformed array and the lambda that maximizes the log-likelihood function (and if alpha is not None too it returns the confidence interval for lambda). Therefore, that’s the lambda that you have to use with the inverse transformation.